# What is the disjoint cycle decomposition of (2,3,7)(3,7,10)?

Tags: group-theory, permutation-cycles

In chapter 3 of *Adventures in Group Theory*, the author gives a "ponderable" that states, "The disjoint cycle decomposition of (2,3,7)(3,7,10) is either (2,3)(7,10) or (2,7)(3,10). Which one is it?"

However, I cannot seem to get either to work and I'm starting to suspect that my understanding of cycles is somehow flawed.

I started with
\begin{array}{|c | c | c | c|}
   \hline
 2 & 3 & 7 & 10 \\
   \hline
 3 & 7 &  &  \\
   \hline
 \end{array}

\begin{array}{|c | c | c | c|}
   \hline
 2 & 3 & 7 & 10 \\
   \hline
  & 7 & 10 &  \\
   \hline
 \end{array}

\begin{array}{|c | c | c | c|}
   \hline
 2 & 3 & 7 & 10 \\
   \hline
  &  & 2 & 3 \\
   \hline
 \end{array}

but no matter how I combine them, I can't seem to reduce them to either one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't read your work.  But, I can explain how I would approach this.

First a disclaimer, some books multiply cycles from left to right, but most work from right to left.

Pick a number.  Since 2 is the smallest in $\{2,3,7,10\}$ lets start there.

$(2$

The rightmost cycle doesn't do anything to 2.  The next cycle takes 2 to 3.

$(2,3$

Since we have ended on 3, we use that as the next number.

The first cycle takes 3 to 7, the next cycle takes 7 to 2, closing the cycle.

$(2,3)$

Now we pick the smallest of the remaining numbers.

$(2,3)(7,$

The first cycle takes 7 to 10, and the second cycle does nothing with 10.

$(2,3)(7,10$

And checking 10 for good measure.

The first cycle takes 10 to 3, and the second takes 3 to 7, closing the second cycle.

$(2,3)(7,10)$

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. I was definitely overthinking it by listing only part of the permutations.